# Change path separator using path module

Tags: node.js, path

Here is my code:

```
var thisImageName = thisRow["imagename"];
var thisImagePath = path.relative("./public", __dirname + "/public/uploads/" + thisImageName + ".jpg");
console.log(thisImagePath); // returns __dirname\public\uploads\
img.src = thisImagePath.split(path.sep).join("/");
```

To get the appropriate image path, I have to split by the path separator and then join the array with the appropriate slash. Does anyone know of a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

John's answer will only replace the first instance of a '\'

```
img.src = thisImagePath.replace(new RegExp('\\' + path.sep, 'g'), '/');
```

Would replace all of them.

You can pass the 'g' flag to `.replace` but this [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 20):

Also, you can always get forward slashes in paths by specifically using the posix path apis:

```
var p = path.posix.relative("./public", imagePath);
```

**EDIT:** This api is only available in versions of node 0.12 or higher.

Comment: I made the same mistake of thinking this would work. As long as each string parameter you pass to `relative` does not have any path separators, it works. But if you do something like `path.posix.relative('./public', 'blah\blah\blah')`, the result is `../blah\blah\blah`. I took that into account when I made this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700461/837251).

Comment: Yes true, this will let you build platform specific paths but not repair existing path strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) string method.

```js
img.src = thisImagePath.replaceAll(path.sep, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was trying to fix system paths. While the accepted answer works for converting strings to URLs (since they're always '/'), it does not work for file system paths. Below is a more comprehensive answer which I think fits the implied question better.

```
const ESCAPE = '\\';
const WRONG_SEPARATOR_FILE_SYSTEM = path.sep === path.win32.sep ?
   path.posix.sep :
   path.win32.sep;

const RGX_WRONG_SEPARATOR_FILE_SYSTEM = new RegExp(ESCAPE + WRONG_SEPARATOR_FILE_SYSTEM, 'g');
const RGX_WRONG_SEPARATOR_URL = new RegExp(ESCAPE + path.win32.sep, 'g');

function strToPath(str) {
    return str.replace(RGX_WRONG_SEPARATOR_FILE_SYSTEM, path.sep);
}

function strToUrl(str) {
    return str.replace(RGX_WRONG_SEPARATOR_URL, '/')
}

// using urls
img.src = strToUrl(thisImagePath)

// using files
strToPath('/some/posix/path') // will be correct regardless of system
strToPath('\some\win\path') // will be correct regardless of system
```